# How to use .document and current user correctly?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i have some code:

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                                      stream: Firestore.instance
                                          .collection('business')
                                          .document(
                                              'XxLqHwyhgAWlnSGQ3rXOBAdY5Rs1')
                                          .snapshots(),
                                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                        Map<String, dynamic>
                                            documentFields =
                                            snapshot.data.data;
                                        return Text(
                                          documentFields["name"],
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 21,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }),
```

and here i must use currentUser():

```
.document('XxLqHwyhgAWlnSGQ3rXOBAdY5Rs1')
```

but i don't know how because it's Text Widget. Please help me guys

Comment: is this `XxLqHwyhgAWlnSGQ3rXOBAdY5Rs1` the user id?

Comment: yes, it's user id

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re trying to do? currentUser() is a method that returns a future. You would have to use a generator if you want to have a stream

Comment: Please have a look at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the `currentUser()` using Firebase Auth, since you are using a `StreamBuilder` widget then first create a method that returns a `Stream`:

```
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async* {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection('business')
        .document(user.uid)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

And then assign the method to the property `stream`:

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
   stream: getData(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
   //..
```